# How to get front and back camera's megapixel that is designed for android device?

Tags: android, hardware

How to identify front and back camera's Megapixel of an android device by using Android code?
I had tried CameraInfo but am not getting megapixel. For example, To identify Model of device we are using this `android.os.Build.MODEL` . Likewise any method to identify Megapixel of front and back camera. Advance thanks for any help.

If the device is `"Videocon A53"` features are (540x960 pixel) display and runs Android 4.1 Jelly Bean, `8-megapixel rear camera`, `2-megapixel front-facing camera`. Now i want to get that `8 megapixel and 2 megapixel by android code`

Comment: this link answer explains very nicely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952469/determining-camera-resolution-i-e-megapixels-programatically-in-android

Comment: Thanks your link made the path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got megapixel by combining three different answers of stack overflow friends.

```
                Camera camera=Camera.open(0);    // For Back Camera
            android.hardware.Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
            List sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
            Camera.Size  result = null;

            ArrayList<Integer> arrayListForWidth = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            ArrayList<Integer> arrayListForHeight = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for (int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++){
                result = (Size) sizes.get(i);
                arrayListForWidth.add(result.width);
                arrayListForHeight.add(result.height);
                Log.debug("PictureSize", "Supported Size: " + result.width + "height : " + result.height);  
                System.out.println("BACK PictureSize Supported Size: " + result.width + "height : " + result.height);  
            } 
            if(arrayListForWidth.size() != 0 && arrayListForHeight.size() != 0){
                System.out.println("Back max W :"+Collections.max(arrayListForWidth));              // Gives Maximum Width
                System.out.println("Back max H :"+Collections.max(arrayListForHeight));                 // Gives Maximum Height
                            System.out.println("Back Megapixel :"+( ((Collections.max(arrayListForWidth)) * (Collections.max(arrayListForHeight))) / 1024000 ) );
            }
            camera.release();

            arrayListForWidth.clear();
            arrayListForHeight.clear();

            camera=Camera.open(1);        //  For Front Camera
            android.hardware.Camera.Parameters params1 = camera.getParameters();
            List sizes1 = params1.getSupportedPictureSizes();
            Camera.Size  result1 = null;
            for (int i=0;i<sizes1.size();i++){
                result1 = (Size) sizes1.get(i);
                arrayListForWidth.add(result1.width);
                arrayListForHeight.add(result1.height);
                Log.debug("PictureSize", "Supported Size: " + result1.width + "height : " + result1.height);  
                System.out.println("FRONT PictureSize Supported Size: " + result1.width + "height : " + result1.height);  
            } 
            if(arrayListForWidth.size() != 0 && arrayListForHeight.size() != 0){
                System.out.println("FRONT max W :"+Collections.max(arrayListForWidth));
                System.out.println("FRONT max H :"+Collections.max(arrayListForHeight));
                            System.out.println("FRONT Megapixel :"+( ((Collections.max(arrayListForWidth)) * (Collections.max(arrayListForHeight))) / 1024000 ) );
            }

            camera.release();
```

For obtaining megapixel, `(Biggest Width x Height) / 1024000 = Megapixel`

Comment: Hi @Sakthimuthiah, My Mobile Phone model is Samsung galaxy star pro GT-S7262. and this mobile specification details shows Samsung [website](http://www.samsung.com/in/consumer/mobile-phone/mobile-phone/smartphone/GT-S7262MKAINU-spec?subsubtype=android-mobiles)/user manual/purchased box having printed only 2MP, but when i am getting max resolution of this mobile is 2048x1536. so it gives approximately 3.072MP by following the above link/above code. so finally i said that above procedure is Not always gives correct result. please help me to find out correct megapixes in android mobile.

Comment: Micromax Bolt A35 device specification shows 2MP(Mega Pixel) but it gives 2592 x 1936 resolution picture. by using above procedure ((2592x1936)/102400)= approximate 5MP it wrong result. So please help me to find out exact megapixels of given android mobile device. please refer my detailed question.[How to find exact camera megapixels in android mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032036/how-to-find-exact-camera-megapixels-in-android-mobile).

Comment: @Sakthimuthiah (Biggest Width x Height) / 1024000 = Megapixel.  Replace 1024000 with 1000000 will give better results

Comment: I will try. Thanks. May i know the reason for replacement of 1000000

Comment: @sathishkumar.challa Sorry, i don't know the way