# How to find exact camera megapixels in android mobile without using camera max picture size

Tags: android, camera

I am Calculating the camera `Megapixel` by using the maximum resolution of camera picture is always NOT giving the correct result.

`i.e Micromax Bolt A35 device specification shows 2MP(Mega Pixel) but it gives 2592 x 1936 resolution  picture. ((2592x1936)/102400)= approximate 5MP.`

eg: My Mobile Phone model is Samsung galaxy star pro GT-S7262. and this mobile specification details shows [Samsung website](http://www.samsung.com/in/consumer/mobile-phone/mobile-phone/smartphone/GT-S7262MKAINU-spec?subsubtype=android-mobiles)/user manual/purchased box having printed only 2MP, but when i am getting max resolution of this mobile is 2048x1536. so it gives approximately 3.072MP by following the below code. so finally i said that below procedure is Not always gives correct result. please help me to find out correct megapixes in android mobile.

```
private int getCameraMinPixels(Camera.Parameters parameters) { 
        float cameraMegaPixel = 0;
        if(parameters!=null)
        {
            Camera.Size size =parameters.getPictureSize();
            cameraMegaPixel = (float) (size.height * size.width) / 1024000f;
        }
        return (int) cameraMegaPixel;
    }
```

Please help me to find camera megapixel.

and i use getall supported picture sizes is

```
private List<Camera.Size> getSortedCameraSupportedPictureSizes(Camera.Parameters parameters)
{
    List<Camera.Size> supportedPreviewSizes = new ArrayList<Camera.Size>(
            parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes());

    Collections.sort(supportedPreviewSizes, new Comparator<Camera.Size>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Camera.Size a, Camera.Size b) {
            int aPixels = a.height * a.width;
            int bPixels = b.height * b.width;
            if (bPixels < aPixels) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (bPixels > aPixels) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });
    return supportedPreviewSizes;
}
```

Comment: @ManishDubey, your posted link and above code both are doing same procedure, but the main problem is **it will not always give correct result.**

Comment: I can only ask, *"Is it the correct model?"*, since Micromax A68 Bolt has 5 MP camera. I think it's a hard fact that it's 5 MP given the picture size. I couldn't find any information that A35 has 5 MP camera though.

Comment: Hi @Andrew T. My Mobile Phone model is Samsung galaxy star pro GT-S7262. and this mobile specification details shows [Samsung website](http://www.samsung.com/in/consumer/mobile-phone/mobile-phone/smartphone/GT-S7262MKAINU-spec?subsubtype=android-mobiles)/user manual/purchased box having printed only 2MP, but when i am getting max resolution of this mobile is 2048x1536. so it gives approximately 3.072MP by following the above link/ above code. so finally i said that above procedure is Not always gives correct result. please help me to find out correct megapixes in android mobile.

Comment: Can you test when taking a picture, is your highest resolution also 2048x1536 (3MP) or 2MP?

Comment: (2048X1536)/1024000=3.072 in my testing i got max resolution image having 2048X1536 in Samsung GT-S7262 mobile.

Comment: @sathishkumar.challa you return the int value so float convert into int so your value get less as per your consideration.
like i have use the Samsung SIII Front camera Max resolution is (1937664/1000000.00) = 1.937664
and print this answer you get 1.9

Comment: @sathishkumar.challa Did you finally manage to get it working?