# how to get camera resolution of the device in an activity ? ( Android )

Tags: android, android-camera, resolution

I'd like to use camera resolution of both front and rear in my activity so that i can distinguish an image (whether taken from back or front camera by checking its resolution).

Comment: This could help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463858/how-to-get-front-and-back-cameras-megapixel-that-is-designed-for-android-device .

Comment: not helping ........ because Camera is depreciated.

Comment: Ok but have not they put anything else instead of Camera ? Normally when anything depreciated it is replaced with new and more robust things.

Comment: yes they putted a whole library i.e.,  cameraManager but i can't find out any specific method for my purpose in this documentation  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

```
            Camera camera=Camera.open(0);    // For Back Camera
        android.hardware.Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        List sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        Camera.Size  result = null;

        ArrayList<Integer> arrayListForWidth = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayListForHeight = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++){
            result = (Size) sizes.get(i);
            arrayListForWidth.add(result.width);
            arrayListForHeight.add(result.height);
            Log.debug("PictureSize", "Supported Size: " + result.width + "height : " + result.height);  
            System.out.println("BACK PictureSize Supported Size: " + result.width + "height : " + result.height);  
        } 
        if(arrayListForWidth.size() != 0 && arrayListForHeight.size() != 0){
            System.out.println("Back max W :"+Collections.max(arrayListForWidth));              // Gives Maximum Width
            System.out.println("Back max H :"+Collections.max(arrayListForHeight));                 // Gives Maximum Height
                        System.out.println("Back Megapixel :"+( ((Collections.max(arrayListForWidth)) * (Collections.max(arrayListForHeight))) / 1024000 ) );
        }
        camera.release();

        arrayListForWidth.clear();
        arrayListForHeight.clear();

        camera=Camera.open(1);        //  For Front Camera
        android.hardware.Camera.Parameters params1 = camera.getParameters();
        List sizes1 = params1.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        Camera.Size  result1 = null;
        for (int i=0;i<sizes1.size();i++){
            result1 = (Size) sizes1.get(i);
            arrayListForWidth.add(result1.width);
            arrayListForHeight.add(result1.height);
            Log.debug("PictureSize", "Supported Size: " + result1.width + "height : " + result1.height);  
            System.out.println("FRONT PictureSize Supported Size: " + result1.width + "height : " + result1.height);  
        } 
        if(arrayListForWidth.size() != 0 && arrayListForHeight.size() != 0){
            System.out.println("FRONT max W :"+Collections.max(arrayListForWidth));
            System.out.println("FRONT max H :"+Collections.max(arrayListForHeight));
                        System.out.println("FRONT Megapixel :"+( ((Collections.max(arrayListForWidth)) * (Collections.max(arrayListForHeight))) / 1024000 ) );
        }

        camera.release();
```

Comment: ya but it is showing camera object as depreciated resulting in " Unfortunately activity has stopped working  "

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html

Comment: please take a look at this

Comment: could you tell specific method to do this job because i can't find out any related method in the documentation for my purpose.