# Google Play - How to disable app from installing on devices with low quality Camera?

Tags: java, android, google-play

My app strongly relies on Camera having at least 8Mpix quality and I would like to exclude devices with lower camera resolution. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there's a way to prevent your program from installing in the first place, but perhaps you could mention on your Google Play page that the program requires a camera of at least 8Mpix quality and have your application notify users that using a camera below this quality will result in the application not behaving correctly. You could have a message appear if the resolution is too low, perhaps.

Refer to this question for how to determine the resolution when the app is running:

[Determining Camera Resolution (i.e. Megapixels) Programatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952469/determining-camera-resolution-i-e-megapixels-programatically-in-android)